# Custom environment with full line width, even when put in e.g. enumerate

Tags: spacing, environments, enumerate

I am writing a latex setup for exercise sheets.

I have defined a "solution" environment, that is only rendered if a boolean is set to true.

Sometimes, **but not always**, I will use a customised enumerate environment for
different parts of an exercise.
When i put the solution inside the enumerate, it will have a smaller linewidth.

How can i make it have the same linewidth as it would have outside of the enumerate?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\newcommand{\problem}[1]{\stepcounter{section}\section*{Problem \sheetNr.\thesection: {#1}}}
\newenvironment{subproblems}{\enumerate[label=\textbf{\alph*}.]}{\endenumerate}

\newif\ifanswers
\NewEnviron{solution}{
    \ifanswers
        \color{purple}
        \par\mbox{}\hrulefill\newline
        \textbf{Solution}:\\
        %
        \expandafter\BODY
        %
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\sheetNr}{1}
\answerstrue

\begin{document}
    \problem{Some Title}
    A problem without subproblems
    \begin{solution}
        The solution has ``full" width.
    \end{solution}
    
    \problem{Another Title}
    \begin{subproblems}
        \item First part
        
        \begin{solution}
            This solution has reduced width
        \end{solution}
        
        \item Second Part
    \end{subproblems}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should have it `\begin{enumerate}[wide]`. B.t.w., for the  labels formatting, it would be simpler to code `[label=\alph*., font=\bfseries]`.

Comment: @Bernard thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to adjust the input slightly - using `\problem` and `\subproblem` as commands rather than a command/environment approach, you can terminate the list after every `\subproblem` and use the [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)-provided `resume` key to resume your sub-problem lists.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\def\restartlist{\relax}%
\setlist[enumerate,1]{before=\restartlist}
\newcommand{\problem}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{section}%
  \section*{Problem \sheetNr.\thesection: #1}%
  \renewcommand{\restartlist}{\expandafter\setcounter\expandafter{\@enumctr}{0}}% Restart numbering
}
\newcommand{\subproblem}[1]{%
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*}.,resume]
    \item #1
  \end{enumerate}
  \renewcommand{\restartlist}{\relax}% Don't restart numbering
}

\newif\ifanswers
\NewEnviron{solution}{%
  \ifanswers
    \par
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
    \color{purple}%
    \leavevmode\hrulefill\par\nobreak
    \textbf{Solution}: \par\nobreak
    \BODY
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\sheetNr}{1}
\answerstrue

\begin{document}

\problem{First problem}
A problem without subproblems.
\begin{solution}
  The solution has ``full'' width.
\end{solution}

\problem{Second problem}
\subproblem{First part}
  
\begin{solution}
  This solution has ``full'' width.
\end{solution}
  
\subproblem{Second part}
    
\end{document}
```

---

If you wish to maintain the current input format (command `\problem` and environment `subproblems`), then you can capture the x-coordinate location and adjust the margins (using [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module and `adjustwidth` from [`changepage`](//ctan.org/pkg/changepage)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{changepage,zref-savepos}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\problem}[1]{\stepcounter{section}\section*{Problem \sheetNr.\thesection: #1}}
\newenvironment{subproblems}{\enumerate[label=\textbf{\alph*}.]}{\endenumerate}

\newif\ifanswers
\newcounter{curanswer}
\NewEnviron{solution}{%
  \ifanswers
    \par
    \stepcounter{curanswer}%
    \mbox{}\zsaveposx{leftmargin-\thecuranswer}%
    \par\vspace{\dimexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{\dimexpr\zposx{leftmargin}sp-\zposx{leftmargin-\thecuranswer}sp}{0pt}
      \color{purple}%
      \leavevmode\hrulefill\par\nobreak
      \textbf{Solution}: \par\nobreak
      \BODY
    \end{adjustwidth}
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\sheetNr}{1}
\answerstrue

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \zsaveposx{leftmargin}%
}

\begin{document}

\problem{First problem}
A problem without subproblems.
\begin{solution}
  The solution has ``full'' width.
\end{solution}

\problem{Second problem}
\begin{subproblems}
  \item First part
  
  \begin{solution}
    This solution has ``full'' width.
  \end{solution}
  
  \item Second part
\end{subproblems}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that works for me!
I ended up making subproblem an environment, because
the contents can become quite long.

May I ask why you end somelines with `%`?

Comment: @JakobUnfried: See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764). Also see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)